# Two meanings of the Elixir tag

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request

There is a programming language called Elixir and a Python library called Elixir. The tag wiki of the [elixir](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/elixir) tag reads the following:

> Elixir is a functional meta-programming aware language built on top of the Erlang VM. It is a dynamic language with flexible syntax with macros support that leverages Erlang's abilities to build concurrent, distributed, fault-tolerant applications with hot code upgrades.

I suggest retagging the posts that are both tagged [elixir](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/elixir) and [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) to [python-elixir](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-elixir). There are only 93 posts tagged [elixir](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/elixir), so it shouldn't be too much of a hassle.

Comment: Apparently, out of the 93, 66 has [tag:python] tag too.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's actually 3. Elixir is not only *"a functional meta-programming aware language built on top of the Erlang VM"* and [*"a declarative layer on top of the SQLAlchemy library."*](http://elixir.ematia.de/trac/wiki) but also provides [*"data visualization for Adobe Flex and AIR"*](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/zones/visualization/demos/elixir.html).

I've created two new tags [python-elixir](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-elixir) for the Python library and [ilog-elixir](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ilog-elixir) for IBM ILOG Elixir, the data visualization package. Both have suggested tag wiki edits pending.

I've cleaned up half of the questions tagged [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) *and* [elixir](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/elixir) and all of the questions tagged [elixir](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/elixir) but *not* [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python).

There's now only [32 questions remaining](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/elixir+python). I've stopped again because I'm spamming the Python active list a bit too much.

---

Update: This is now [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed). There are a few questions with the tag [python-elixir](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-elixir) in the close votes queue (one I think I'm now regretting) if anyone wants to finish the job using a quick filter.

Comment: Shouldn't we also rename `elixir` to `elixir-language` to remove the temptation to tag incorrectly?

Comment: If you want to @Charles. I didn't as it's not like [tag:false] so there's less chance and there's only 3 tags all with excerpts so it's pretty obvious (I hope) which is which. Maybe I have more faith in people than I thought I did! Thinking about it, yes you're right... there's no chance people will do this right :-). People will then, of course, just re-create the elixir tag,*sigh*.

Comment: Oh, don't worry about it coming back.  I can put it on my list of *54* tags I keep dead...